# System.Web.Optimization.Bundle vs. WebEssentials bundling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

What are the differences between **System.Web.Optimization.Bundle** and the bundling operation in **WebEssentials** Visual Studio plugin?
I mean not only the final result which should be pretty much the same, but also the internals, esp. the differences (if any) in both Debug and Release mode.
And, finally, what do I gain and what do I loose choosing one or another?

Answer (score 1):

As we know **System.Web.Optimization.Bundle** is mainly used for bundling the js or css files to reduce page size or loading issues but **web Essentials** is a collection of (mostly) web-related enhancements to Visual Studio.
It includes lots of new IntelliSense completions (especially for CSS), new BrowserLink features, automatic JSHint for Javascript files, new warnings for HTML and CSS, and many other features. Any web-related functionality you want to add should probably go here.

In details if you want to check then below links might be useful.

1. For Bundling and manification
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification
2. For Web Essential 
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/11/05/making-web-development-wonderful-again-with-web-essentials/

Answer (score 0):

I use both approaches time to time. The result is almost the same (size of output files, compile time etc).

1. **System.Web.Optimization**. You maintain functionality through *.cs and *.cshtml files.
2. **Web Essentials**. You maintain functionality through context menu and config accumulated in .json(xml) files.

But you can not use System.Web.Optimization approach if you develop static html page (no server side at all)